# Is Monsky's theorem provable in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$?

Tags: lo.logic, mg.metric-geometry, reverse-math

[Monsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky%27s_theorem) states that it is not possible to dissect a square into an odd number of triangles of equal area. Monsky's proof attracted attention in part because it unexpectedly made use of the fact that the 2-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$.  There is no canonical way to extend the 2-adic valuation to transcendental extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, so this step of the proof has a highly arbitrary and nonconstructive feel to it.  Most people would not expect that such non-canonical choices would be necessary to prove something as concrete as Monsky's theorem.  (Occasionally someone will even [ask whether Monsky's proof makes essential use of the axiom of choice](https://mathoverflow.net/q/107043), but the answer is no.)

The aforementioned "nonconstructive feel" leads me to ask the following question. In the language of [Subsystems of Second-Order Arithmetic](https://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa/chapter1.pdf), can Monsky's theorem be proved in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$?  A potential sticking point might be the existence of transcendence bases, which is something that doesn't kick in until the $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ level. So for example, if we're handed some candidate vertices with coordinates that involve (say) the numbers $e$ and $\pi$, then we have no effective way to determine whether $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent.  But maybe we don't really need transcendence bases per se.  Since we're using classical logic, perhaps we can split into two cases, according to whether $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically dependent or not, and argue that the desired conclusion follows in either case?

Comment: Isn't the question of whether such a dissection exists consisting of a fixed number $n$ of triangles equivalent to a first-order statement in the language of real closed fields? If so that would imply that if a dissection exists then a dissection exists with all coordinates algebraic (assuming the square's coordinates are algebraic), right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm almost surely remembering incorrectly but isn't there a counterexample by Micha Perles that such reasoning is not always correct? I'm thinking of some kind of finite combinatorial configuration that can be realized in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but cannot be realized in $K^n$ for any finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais That doesn't sound right to me. See for example the paper by Richter-Gebert and Ziegler, [Realization spaces of 4-polytopes are universal](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1995-32-04/S0273-0979-1995-00604-X/S0273-0979-1995-00604-X.pdf). To realize all 4-polytopes, you need all algebraic numbers, but I don't think you ever need transcendental numbers. Qiaochu's argument sounds convincing to me, but can that claim be proved in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$?

Comment: Yeah, I think I must have reversed quantifiers due to bad memory. Anyway, I think I have an argument that might work but it's not fully fleshed out...

Comment: The first idea is that Monsky's argument works fine for a finitely generated real extension $\mathbb{Q}(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_k)$ provided we have a decision procedure for which polynomial inequalities are true. (There is no requirement for the $t$s to be algebraic, as Qiaochu suggested, but that does help for the decision process.) [continued]

Comment: The second idea is that we may be able to guess the correct decision procedure with finitely many choices. I think this is true (but not at all obvious) if the $t$s are algebraic but I don't think this is true if we allow transcendentals. [continued]

Comment: The third idea is that in $\mathsf{WKL}_0$ we can actually make infinitely guesses in a progressive manner. More technically, if $t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_k$ are fixed real numbers the decision procedure we need is a $\Pi^0_1$ singleton. [continued]

Comment: The fourth and final idea is that some conservation result for $\mathsf{WKL}_0$ over $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ will allow to conclude the result over $\mathsf{RCA}_0$.

Comment: It's pretty late here for me to try to work this out and, to be honest, any one of these four steps could fail upon further investigation.

Comment: PS: The reason I think the algebraic case is easier is that $\mathbb{Q}(t_1,\ldots,t_k)$ is then a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the possibilities positive cone in that space could be determined by finitely many guesses.

Comment: We don't know whether $e$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent. We don't even know whether $e+\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But we can make guesses at the outset so long as one of the guesses must be right. In $\mathsf{RCA}_0$, we're allowed finitely many guesses because of the law of excluded middle.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't an answer to your question because I have no idea whether this argument can be carried out in $RCA_0$, but this fact doesn't appear to be mentioned anywhere easily accessible through googling about Monsky's theorem so it seems good to document it somewhere (assuming I didn't make a mistake!). We can say the following (unless I am horribly mistaken about something!):

> **Claim 1:** A system of polynomial equations $P_1(x_1, \dots x_n) = \dots = P_k(x_1, \dots x_n)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a solution over $\mathbb{R}$ iff it has a solution over the real algebraic numbers $\mathbb{R} \cap \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

> **Claim 2:** For a fixed positive integer $k$, Monsky's theorem for subdivisions into $2k+1$ triangles is equivalent to the statement that no member of a specific finite set of systems of polynomial equations has a solution over $\mathbb{R}$.

The upshot is that Monsky's theorem is true over $\mathbb{R}$ iff it's true over $\mathbb{R} \cap \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, and hence that we only need to extend the $2$-adic valuation to the *finite* extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by the coordinates of a potential algebraic counterexample, which is just a number field $K$. And this can be done with no shenanigans whatsoever, since it suffices to choose a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ lying over $(2)$. So there is no need, as far as I can tell, to consider even a single transcendental number in the argument.

Claim 1 follows from the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is elementary equivalent to any real closed field but I believe it should also have a more elementary proof using elimination theory; hopefully someone else can fill in the details and say what exactly is needed in the proof.

Claim 2 is the usual reduction of Euclidean geometry to the theory of real closed fields: an equal-area dissection of the unit square into $2k+1$ triangles consists of the coordinates of a finite collection of points together with one of a finite set of finitely many assertions that these points 1) lie inside the unit square, and 2) define triangles with area $\frac{1}{2k+1}$ (we may want to draw different lines between the points to define different sets of triangles but for $k$ fixed there are only finitely many possible configurations). A real number $x$ lies in $[0, 1]$ iff $\exists y_1 : x = y_1^2$ and $\exists y_2 : 1 - x = y_2^2$, and the area of a triangle is a quadratic polynomial in the coordinates of its vertices, so the conclusion is that for fixed $k$ the existence of an equal-area dissection into $2k+1$ triangles is equivalent to the existence of a solution to one of a finite set of systems of quadratic polynomials.